# Emacs: desktop does not retrieve frame names

Tags: emacs

All the frames in my session have an explicit name set with `set-frame-name`, but when the session is restored through desktop, the names of the frames are not retrieved.

Tried `emacs -Q`: after starting I change the frame name with `set-frame-name`, then `desktop-save` and quit emacs. I reboot with `emacs -Q` and do `desktop-read`, but the frame name is not restored. I have looked at `.emacs.desktop` and I don't see the name of the frame.

Do I need any specific configuration to get the frames to recover their names?

I am using emacs 27.1 with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Seems like that should work. Do you see the same thing if you remove everything irrelevant from your init file, e.g. start Emacs with `emacs -Q` and do whatever you need to do to save a desktop and later restore it? If you don't see the problem with `emacs -Q` then bisect your init file to find the problem.

Comment: Tried `emacs -Q`: after starting I change the frame name with `set-frame-name`, then `desktop-save` and quit emacs.

I reboot with `emacs -Q` and do `desktop-read`, but the frame name is not restored.

I have looked at `.emacs.desktop` and I don't see the name of the frame.

Comment: OK, good. You might want to add that info to the question, to provide more info. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution by checking the `frameset.el` file.

It was enough for me to put the following line in the `init.el` (or `.emacs`) file:

`(push '(name . nil) frameset-filter-alist)`

Now `desktop.el` already retrieves the names of the frames set with `set-frame-name`

This work because `frameset-filter-alist` is a copy of `frameset-persistent-filter-alist` and the `name` parameter is initially set to neither save (`desktop-save`) nor retrieve (`desktop-read`)

With `(push '(name . nil) frameset-filter-alist)` this behavior is override.